# Make Objective-C method return anything

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, nserror

I am using this method below to get data from a URL, but I want to make it return an error if the `statusCode` is not equal to 200.

```
+ (NSData *)getData:(NSString *) url {
    NSURL *urlNS = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlNS];
    NSError * error = nil;
    NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;
    NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
    int statusCode = [urlResponse statusCode];
    if(statusCode == 200) {
        return data;
    } else {
        //return the error object which is not NSData or which is converted to NSData
    }
}
```

**My question**

Can I somehow return my error **(it will be the error variable defined above)** in a non NSData object or can I maybe convert my error to NSData?

Comment: Don't prefix the method with `get`;  that is reserved for a special case that this is not.   `downloadData:error:` would seem more appropriate.

Comment: Sharp eyes as usual, @bbum

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The usual convention is to return nil if there's an error.

If you also want to provide an error, the usual thing is to provide an extra parameter by indirection (`NSError**`).

Example:

```
+ (id)stringWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error
```

> **Return Value**
>
> A string created by reading data from the file named by path using the encoding, enc. If the file can’t be opened or there is an encoding error, returns nil.

Cocoa uses this pattern *very* heavily.

Comment: So it would be... `+ (id)getData:(NSString *) url error:(NSError **)error`?

Comment: When I say `return error;` I get an error: "Implicit conversion of an indirect pointer to"..."is disallowed by ARC." How do I fix that?

Comment: You shouldn't `return error;`, you need to set the error `if (errorPtr) *errorPtr = error;` and then `return nil;`  (Note: this presumes `errorPtr` to be the name of the `NSError **` argument in the method declaration).   It also means you need to create `error` yourself.

Comment: @JacquesBlom This might help on `NSError**`: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch01.html#_pointer_parameters_and_the_address_operator This will help on the convention of returning nil: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch03.html#_instance_references_initialization_and_nil